# Is there an "Addable" protocol or abstract base class in Python? If not how would one define it?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

The [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) contains many protocols and abstract base classes that formally specify protocols which are informally described in [the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), so they can be used for type hints.

However I was unable to find such a protocol or abstract base class for objects that support `__add__`. Is there any formal specification of such a protocol? If not how would such an implementation look like?

**Update:**

Since I'm interested in such a class for the purpose of typing, such a class would only be useful if it's fully type itself, like the examples in the `typing` module.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no pre-defined `Addable` protocol. You can definie one yourself:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


class Addable(Protocol):
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T: ...
```

This protocol requires that both summands and the result share a common ancestor type.

The protocol can then be used as follows:

```py
Tadd = TypeVar("Tadd", bound=Addable)


def my_sum(*args: Tadd, acc: Tadd) -> Tadd:
    res = acc
    for value in args:
        res += value

    return res


my_sum("a", "b", "c", acc="") # correct, returns string "abc"
my_sum(1, 2, 6, acc=0) # correct, returns int 9
my_sum(1, 2.0, 6, acc=0) # correct, returns float 9.0
my_sum(True, False, False, acc=False) # correct, returns bool 1 (mypy reveal_type returns bool, running it in python leads to result 1)

my_sum(True, False, 1, acc=1.0) # incorrect IMHO, but not detected by mypy, returns float 3.0

my_sum(1, 2, 6, acc="") # incorrect, detected by mypy
my_sum(1, 2, "6", acc=0) # incorrect, detected by mypy
```

Comment: Pylance is giving me an error on each of the examples you've added - eg with the 2nd: `Argument of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to parameter "args" of type "Tadd@my_sum" in function "my_sum"` (...) `Type "(__value: int, /) -> int" cannot be assigned to type "(other: int) -> int"`

Answer (score 1):

You could define one yourself using the [abc module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). The ABC metaclass that is provided there allows you to define a `__subclasshook__`, in which you can check for class methods such as `__add__`. If this method is defined for a certain class, it is then considered a subclass of that abc.

```py
from abc import ABC

class Addable(ABC):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Addable:
            if any("__add__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented

class Adder():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __add__(self, x):
        return x + self.x

inst = Adder(5)

# >>> isinstance(inst, Addable)
# True
# >>> issubclass(Adder, Addable)
# True
```

Comment: Without type hints it's very straightforward, it's even easier if you use the `Protocol` class introduced in python 3.8. But without type hints this isn't every helpful for typing.

Comment: I see, but then what's wrong with defining a `Protocol` that supports `__add__`?
Both mypy and pyright (the static type checker of VSCode) accept objects that support `__add__` if the protocol is specified that way.

Answer (score 1):

There exists such a protocol. Just not in the code that's usually executed...
There exists a special package called [`typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed) that's used by type-checkers to add type-hints to code that isn't implemented with any type-hints... The `typeshed` package doesn't exist during runtime though.

So you can use `_typeshed.SupportsAdd` during type-checking - but to check during execution you'd need to check for the `__add__` method dynamically **or** you implement the `SupportsAdd` protocol yourself...

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _typeshed import SupportsAdd


# SupportsAdd must always be written in quotation marks when used later...
def require_adding_str_results_in_int(a_obj: "SupportsAdd[str, int]"):
    # the type checker guarantees that this should work now
    assert type(a_obj + "a str") == int

    # to check during runtime though you'd probably use
    assert hasattr(a_obj, "__add__")
```

Hope that helped...
Most likely it's the best way to implement your own protocol and use the [`@runtime_checkable`](https://github.com/python/typeshed) decorator. You can look at the source code of typeshed to get inspirations.